# Unusual hex log in Apache24 access.log

Tags: apache-2.4

We are seeing very large number of lines in the access.log like below:

"\xf7\x13v\x01!\b\x02\"\x1d" 400 226

They are coming from a large number of sources that legitimately use the HTTP server so we believe it’s a configuration problem.

I can’t see any of the hex values in rfc5246 and network analysis proves they are using the correct configured TLS port for Apache, however I’ve not seen any TLS handshakes.

Answer (score 0):

Such strings can often be exploit tests but if they are coming from legitimate sources, by which I assume they are addresses that are known to you, they could be some kind of port check or a keepalive process from an application - would that make sense in this context?

Comment: Keep-alives are a reasonable assumption, given they are known source IP addresses.